# how to control mouse pointer with head movement using emguCV C#?

Tags: c#, mouse, emgucv

I am developing a system just like Camera mouse or other face control mouse, I have implemented all the functionality, the mouse pointer is also moving well, but I want to create the movement smooth just like the mouse control the pointer. the code I am using is:

```
        if (startButton == true)
        {
            try
            {
                cap = new Capture();
                pictureBox1.Image = cap.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>().Bitmap;
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error:" + exp);
            }
            _cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(Application.StartupPath + "/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
            eye_cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(Application.StartupPath + "/haarcascade_eye.xml");

            timer1.Start();
        }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var imageFrame = cap.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>().Flip(FlipType.Horizontal))
        {
            if (imageFrame != null)
            {
                var grayframe = imageFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();

                var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty); //the actual face detection happens here

                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    if(Configure.FaceBoxCheck==true)
                    imageFrame.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.LightGreen), 2); //the detected face(s) is highlighted here using a box that is drawn around it/them
                    Int32 yCoordStartSearchEyes = face.Top + (face.Height * 3 / 11);
                    Point startingPointSearchEyes = new Point(face.X, yCoordStartSearchEyes);
                    Size searchEyesAreaSize = new Size(face.Width, (face.Height * 3 / 11));
                    Rectangle possibleROI_eyes = new Rectangle(startingPointSearchEyes, searchEyesAreaSize);

                    int widthNav = (imageFrame.Width / 11 * 3);
                    int heightNav = (imageFrame.Height / 11 * 3);
                    Rectangle nav = new Rectangle(new Point(imageFrame.Width / 2 - widthNav / 2, imageFrame.Height / 2 - heightNav / 2), new Size(widthNav, heightNav));
                    imageFrame.Draw(nav, new Bgr(Color.Lavender), 3);
                    Point cursor = new Point(face.X + searchEyesAreaSize.Width / 2, yCoordStartSearchEyes + searchEyesAreaSize.Height / 2);
                    grayframe.ROI = possibleROI_eyes;
                    var eyes = eye_cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 2.15, 3, Size.Empty);

                    foreach (var eye in eyes)
                    {
                      //imageFrame.Draw(eye, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                        if(Configure.EyeBoxCheck==true)
                        imageFrame.Draw(possibleROI_eyes, new Bgr(Color.DarkGreen), 2);
                        if (nav.Left < cursor.X && cursor.X < (nav.Left + nav.Width) && nav.Top < cursor.Y && cursor.Y < nav.Top + nav.Height)
                        {
                            LineSegment2D CursorDraw = new LineSegment2D(cursor, new Point(cursor.X, cursor.Y + 1));

                            imageFrame.Draw(CursorDraw, new Bgr(Color.White), 3);
                            //we compute new cursor coordinate using a simple scale based on frame width and height
                            int xCoord = (imageFrame.Width * (cursor.X - nav.Left)) / nav.Width;
                            int yCoord = (imageFrame.Height * (cursor.Y - nav.Top)) / nav.Height;
                            //We set our new cursor position
                            Cursor.Position = new Point(xCoord * 2, yCoord *2);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I haven't tried emgucv, but the problem seems to be that the position transition is not smooth. I think you should calculate a "Path" between the current mouse position and the next calculated position. Then you'll have to "manually" move the mouse along that path. I don't know if this make sense

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm sure there are a lot of other better ways, but this is a quick&dirty way of moving cursor position in a "Smooth" way from point a to point b. Of course this implementation can and should be optimized using a different thread instead of using `Application.DoEvents()` to avoid blocking the UI thread, but i hope this gets you on the track. First, how you should use it. Instead of:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(xCoord * 2, yCoord *2);
```

You should do this:

```
MoveCursorSmooth(Cursor.Position, new Point(xCoord * 2, yCoord *2));
```

Now, the implementation of `MoveCursorSmooth`:

```
    private void MoveCursorSmooth(Point a, Point b)
    {
        var step = 5;
        var left = Math.Min(a.X, b.X);
        var right = Math.Max(a.X, b.X);
        int width = right - left;

        var top = a.Y;
        var bottom = b.Y;
        int height = bottom - top;

        if (width > height)
        {
            double slope = (double)height / (double)width;
            if (a.X <= b.X) 
                for (int x = 1; x < width; ++x) 
                {
                    Cursor.Position = new Point((left + x), (a.Y + ((int)(slope * x + 0.5))));
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(step);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
            else
                for (int x = 1; x < width; ++x) // xOffset
                {
                    Cursor.Position = new Point((right - x), (a.Y + ((int)(slope * x + 0.5))));
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(step);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
        }
        else
        {

            double slope = (double)width / (double)height;
            if (a.X <= b.X)
            {
                for (int y = 1; y < height; ++y)
                {
                    Cursor.Position = new Point((a.X + ((int)(slope * y + 0.5))), (top + y));
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(step);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int y = 1; y < height; ++y)
                {
                    Cursor.Position = new Point((b.X + ((int)(slope * y + 0.5))), (bottom - y));
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(step);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12558966/579895)

Comment: this code does make smooth movement but the imagebox is not working  the video is hanging, i think there is error in thread and as i close the form application runs and mouse pointer also make movements at particular  place,
P.S movement is also automatic does not follow head movement.

Comment: As i told you, this is only something to get you on the track. This code should be in another thread, i'm not surprised the video hangs. About the movement not following head movement, you are the one that tells the destination point of the mouse, but you'd probably should to implement some kind of "Cancel" signal, because once you call this method with a destination, the mouse would go on moving until it reaches the destination. This is just to get you on the track, but of course you need to improve it a lot.