# Find specific point between 2 points - three.js

Tags: vector, three.js, distance, points

How can I find a point ( C (x,y,z) ) between 2 points ( A(x,y,z) , B(x,y,z) ) in a thgree.js scene?

I know that with this: [mid point](https://www.easycalculation.com/analytical/images/mid-point3-formula.gif) I can find the middle point between them, but I don't want the middle point, I want to find the point which is between them and also has distance a from the A point?

in this picture you can see what I mean :

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Plenty of info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250419/finding-points-on-a-line-with-a-given-distance

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Basically you need to get the direction vector between the two points (D), normalize it, and you'll use it for getting the new point in the way: `NewPoint = PointA + D*Length`.

You could use length normalized (0..1) or as an absolute value from 0 to length of the direction vector.

Here you can see some examples using both methods:

Using absolute value:

```
function getPointInBetweenByLen(pointA, pointB, length) {
    
    var dir = pointB.clone().sub(pointA).normalize().multiplyScalar(length);
    return pointA.clone().add(dir);
       
}
```

And to use with percentage (0..1)

```
function getPointInBetweenByPerc(pointA, pointB, percentage) {
    
    var dir = pointB.clone().sub(pointA);
    var len = dir.length();
    dir = dir.normalize().multiplyScalar(len*percentage);
    return pointA.clone().add(dir);
       
}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/8mnqjsge/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is for **THREE.JS** and I end up looking for something similar in **Babylon JS**.

Just in case if you are using **Babylon JS** `Vector3` then the formula would translate to:

```
function getPointInBetweenByPerc(pointA, pointB, percentage) {

    var dir = pointB.clone().subtract(pointA);
    var length = dir.length();
    dir = dir.normalize().scale(length *percentage);
    return pointA.clone().add(dir);

  }
```

Hope it help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as `lerp` between two points

e.g. in Three:

```
C = new Three.Vector3()
C.lerpVectors(A, B, a)
```

also in generic this is just a single **lerp** (linear interpolation) math (basically `(a * t) + b * (1 - t)`) on each axis. Lerp can be described as follows:

```
function lerp (a,  b,  t) {
    return a + t * (b - a)
}
```

in your case (see above) :

```
A = {
  x: lerp(A.x, B.x, a),
  y: lerp(A.y, B.y, a),
  z: lerp(A.z, B.z, a)
}
```